# Proof of a Proposition

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am having trouble trying to proof a proposition that appears in a paper.
It begins with
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\int_{v_{i}^{*}}^{\bar{v}}(1-F(u))u\mathrm{d}G(u)-\int_{\underline{v}}^{v_{i}^{*}}F(u)u\mathrm{d}G(u)]\geq0$

where $G(u)=F(u)^{n-1}$.

For a specific subcase, we have that for one individual, say for $i=1$, $r_1=1\implies v_{1}^{*}=\bar{v}$ while for the remaining $n-1$ individuals $r_{i}=0\implies v_{i}^{*}=\underline{v}$. $\bar{v}$ and $\underline{v}$ represent the extremes of te support of a certain distribution. In the case of a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ we have $\bar{v}=1,\underline{v}=0$. Moreover, $F(u)=u$ and $G(u)=F(u)^{n-1}=u^{n-1}$. Since the paper uses Stieltjes integrals, if I understood them correctly we can write $\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\int_{v_{i}^{*}}^{\bar{v}}(1-u)u(n-1)u^{n-2}\mathrm{d}u-\int_{\underline{v}}^{v_{i}^{*}}u*u(n-1)u^{n-2}\mathrm{d}u]\geq0$. According to the proposition, at the end we should have $-\int_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}}F^{n-1}\mathrm{d}v+\int_{\underline{v}}^{\bar{v}}F^n\mathrm{d}v\geq0$. This should be valid for any function $F$, provided it is a CDF.

If I try to get that result, I proceed as follows:

Since we only have one individual with $v_{i}^{*}=\bar{v}=1$ and the remaining $(n-1)$ have $v_{i}^{*}=\underline{v}=0$ I split the sum as follows

$-\int_{0}^{1}u*u*(n-1)u^{n-2}\mathrm{d}u+(n-1)\int_{0}^{1}u(n-1)*u^{n-2}\mathrm{d}u-(n-1)\int_{0}^{1}u*u*(n-1)*u^{n-2}\mathrm{d}u$ which is equal to $-n\int_{0}^{1}u\mathrm{d}u+(n-1)\int_{0}^{1}u^{n-1}\mathrm{d}u$ which is almost the opposite of what the proposition says.

What am I doing wrong?

If someone wonders where the proposition comes from, it is Proposition 2 in Clamton, Gibbons, Klemperer (1987): http://web.mit.edu/rgibbons/www/Gibbons_Cramton_Klemperer_Dissolving%20a%20Partnership%20Efficiently.pdf

Thank you.